# Cannot change UITableView after view is displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UINavigationController that pushes a custom UITableViewController onto the stack. This pushed view controller, which is also the the table view delegate and data source, will then need to download the required data from the internet before it can be displayed. This process of downloading also happens when the user scrolls to the bottom of the the table view, in which the new downloaded data is appended to the bottom of the table view.

I want to notify the user that this downloading is occurring. The problem is that I have tried many methods, yet the table view does not display any of the changes I have made before the downloading occurs. I have encapsulated the notification and download into a single method within my custom UITableViewController class:

```
- (void) extractArticlesFromURL:(NSURL) url
{   
    // 1st method - set alpha
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.2;

    // 2nd method - push an overlay while downloading
    UIViewController* overlay = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    overlay.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:overlay animated:NO];

    // 3rd method - introduce a BOOL isLoading, which is used in data source
    // and delegate methods in an attempt to change display
    isLoading = YES;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];

    // Spend a few seconds downloading data which is stored in an
    // array which is accessed during UITableViewDelegate method calls...

    self.tableView.alpha = 1;
    isLoading = NO;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I call this particular method in `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView`, which is definitely getting called as the table view is appended with new data but with no change in display during the downloading. I do not mind the app freezing up, it's just it does not update the display before it freezes.

If it helps, I am using XCode 4.3.2 using LLVM 3.1, and testing the functionality with iPhone Simulator 5.1. This component of the application is single-threaded.

Comment: Try showing a notification and then calling a timer or wait block so that your download starts a short time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your view frozen because you are taking lots of time to complete these actions and you are running in the main thread.

The best way to unfreeze the view is to collect all the remote data using a separate thread. When you end loading data, you call your main controller and tell it to update the views (update tables, push new controller, etc).

Also, when you start loading data in the separate thread, you can update your view in the main thread i.e. adding a spinning wheel or some "Loading ..." message on screen.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my wording of the question to better target my problem. All attempts to change display right before I start downloading are not being applied which is what I want to fix.

Comment: You have to use a separate thread anyway. I had a similar issue in the past, with view freezing just before or just after being modified.

Comment: So I managed to fix this issue using asynchronous NSURLConnection. It all came down the first principles of running software on a fast micro with an operating system and relatively slow IO; the method calls to change the display to do reach its target by the time the download starts (which was initially done on the main thread). Once the download had finished, the change-back display method was called and these two calls were queued and executed sequentially at processor speed, so the display never appeared to change. Thanks heaps! (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is just about to give the tips, not about implementation.

Well, you can use @synchronize method in your method for asynchronous call, and you can identify the last row of your tableView whenever user scrolls the tableView then you can call the refresh/update method which just update your data model or else you can put one refresh button on navigation bar to allow user to download more items or else you can run the timer which just download the latest data from your server if it is not differ from your cache model. You should always cache the data model.